# Monitor folder size

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, monitoring, resources

Is there a way to monitor and log folder size in Bash/Ubuntu? I'm running some computations and I need to know how much disk space they need. They may create some temporary folders for a few minutes/hours.

In fact, I need only a peak size of this folder.

Comment: Is polling good enough?

Comment: $Eugen, I was hoping there is some bash command for this or sth. like this.

Comment: A two-liner in bash to poll, but no follower I am aware of

Answer (score 0):

you might try something like:

watch "du -skh /your-directory"

If size/number of file increases set interval with "-n" to much greater than 2 sec

Best,

Bodo

Comment: Hi, I tried that but the content of the log file looks bad, if I do:
watch -n 1 "du -skh working_directory" >> resMon.txt

Answer (score 0):

watch is not created to produce log-files.

What you search is something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    du -skh /your-directory
    echo "Press [CTRL+C] to stop.."
    sleep 1
done
```